# SSRS Report Manager Data Source and Catalog table discrepancy

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, datasource

We recently migrated our SQL Environments from SQL Server 2012 to SQL Server 2016. I updated the connection string in each SQL Server shared data source in the SSRS Report Manager (Portal). That's working as expected.

However, when I query the catalog table (content column) in the `ReportServer` database for the data sources we changed, the table still keeps the old connection string, no matter what, while the Report Manager is showing the right one.

Where is the new connection string stored then? Why is it not updated? I have a report to get that from the catalog table and now it is not working.

Thanks!